# Gitlab Error - Repository doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, gitlab

I had installed `gitlab 6` a month ago, there was no problem and all was working fine, until recently it started showing me the following error, when I push into a newly created repository it gives me the following error:

```
fatal: '/home/git/repositories/my_username/tester.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Output of `git remote -v` is as follows:

```
origin  git@my_server.com:username/tester.git (fetch)
origin  git@my_server.com:username/tester.git (push)
```

I also have no issue in pulling and pushing to my old repositories that are in gitlab.

What could be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: What does `git remote -v` returns in your local new repo that you are trying to push?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a project in Gitlab - Gitlab adds a job to the queue to create a repository in the directory where the repository is stored. This operation is performed asynchronously by reason of the fact that for its implementation meets the component gitlab-shell. You can see the logs of his work (ex /home/git/gitlab-shell/gitlab-shell.log) in order to learn more details about a potential problem, but if it worked before - hardly something went wrong there.

Most likely your problem is related to the fact that the queue was either loaded or was not started or did not work correctly. Restarting of Sidekiq solves this problem. You can restart it by running the command:

```
bundle exec rake sidekiq:restart
```